# Phonegap 2.1 : custom push notification text subscription on iOS

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I use the "push notification" plugin of phonegap on my iOS application with jquerymobile.

at the first launch, a notifcation ask to user if he want receive "push notification" for my application.
Is it possible to customize this text?

After accept this first "subscription notification", if i remove my App of the device and put back it, no "subscription notification" is ask to user.
How can i show this "subscription notification" again when user remove my App and put back it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your application needs live notifications while it is in foreground, rather that background notifications that require authorization at first launch, you should consider a Web Push solution for PhoneGap. I can mention Lightstreamer ( http://www.lightstreamer.com ). You can find a PhoneGap tutorial here: http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2012/08/lightstreamer-in-phonegap-app.html

Comment: Could you please post your code, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hello, i just look the phonegap readme : [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification) they just forgot to say put the import code on the AppDelegate.m header
'code' #import "PushNotification.h" 'code'